# Can not run program, permission denied erro13 Jenkins

Tags: java, android, jenkins

I created a new job for android new project on Jenkin. Whenever I run the job I got error java.io.ioexception error 13 permission denied. Jenkin says unable to run program gradlew. I know gradlew script need execution permissions according to the error explanation . I granted these and re run the jenkin job. I still get the same error. Jenkin revert the execution permission back after build. When I create new job from existing job and configured with old projects repository , it runs fine. when I configured with new project repository it raised permission issues.  I played a lot with permission but no success. I also compared old and new project script file. There was few lines difference but it shouldn't be an issue. Any one can guide me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is clearly a permission issue.

> ```
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "<http://jenkins.gradlew"
> error=13, Permission denied
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
> ```

There are two solutions to resolve the gradlew permission issue.

- Go to Jenkin Job configuration
- Go to Build tab and check  gradlew executable.

Jenkin will change the permission when you press build now. Keep in mind that these changes are uncommitted.  The process works fine if your job is not a release job. If it is release job it creates another issue that I came across.

> ```
> :workspace:app:checkCommitNeeded FAILED
> :app:release FAILED
>
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':workspace:app:checkCommitNeeded'.
> > You have uncommitted files:
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>    M gradlew
> ```

So work around is

commit gradlew with executable bit set:

> ```
> git update-index --chmod=+x gradlew
> git commit
> ```

Then you will no longer need the jenkins setting to set it executable, which is the workaround causing  the 2nd issue.

Hopefully it would save someone time because I spent hours for the work around.

Answer (score 8):

I was using Github for source code management. It was fetching code there and was updating it every single time, so changing it to +x before submitting my Jenkins job didn't help.
In Linux the project is at /.jenkins/workspace/MyProjectName/SomeSubFolder/gradlew - and it was loosing +x evereytime a new job was submitted (to 644, I think).

The solution was to select the `Make gradlew executable` checkbox (in `Build --> Use Gradle Wrapper`) -  it is 755 now, and is executing gradle tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a jenkinsfile for your job configuration?
If so you need to add the permission change for gradlew there.

```
sh 'chmod 755 ./gradlew'
```

It sounds like your gradlew is being replaced each time with a version that doesn't have the execute permission set so you will need to do it as part of the jenkins job either via a script or the jenkinsfile.

Comment: Thanks Kirsten, I am not using jenkinfile for the configuration. Could you explain little more about as part of the Jenkins job.

Comment: Does jenkins execute a script for your build? or does your jenkins job contain the command to execute your build?